# Installing scikit-learn with pip: are there multiple python versions installed on my computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scikit-learn, pip

I'm trying to install `scikit-learn` with pip by using `pip install scikit-learn`
and I got this message:

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st,
> 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021.
> More details about Python 2 support in pip can be found at
> https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
> pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality.
>
> WARNING: The scripts f2py, f2py2 and f2py2.7 are installed in '/Users/my_name/Library/Python/2.7/bin' which is not on PATH.
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

However, when I type `python --version` it says that my version is 3.7.4. Are python 2.7 and 3.7 both installed on my computer then? If so, is there a way I can get rid of 2.7? Also, I still get a `ModuleNotFoundError` when I do `from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift` in the mu_editor. I think it's because pip is installing the modules to the python 2.7 directory or something, instead of the python 3.7.4 directory that the mu_editor is connected to. Is there any way I can install the packages to the python 3.7.4 directory instead of the 2.7 one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `python -v` to check default python installation. If it is the version you are using, continue with `python` instead of `python3`.

Now run `python3 -m pip install scikit-learn`
If you are on a Mac, DO NOT DELETE PYTHON 2.7. It is needed for your system to run properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, I get a syntax error when I do python3 -m pip install scikit-learn:  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 -m pip install scikit-learn
                          ^
Did you also get this? Thanks again!

Comment: If you just type pip, does it prompt you to update?

Comment: I just typed pip and it turns out I don't even have pip installed on python 3, only python 2.7. I installed it, and did python3 -m pip install scikit-learn, and it works now! Thanks so much :)

Comment: If it hasn't come with you're installation of python, you'll need to install it manually. Instructions found here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/.

Answer (score 0):

plz use this command

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

In order to check your installation you can use

```
python -m pip show scikit-learn  # to see which version and where scikit-learn is installed
python -m pip freeze  # to see all packages installed in the active virtualenv
python -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"
```

see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html